# I want to call another class in tkinter. i have 2 classes and i can't call the database class below my window class

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am new to tkinter and i have only started working on Tkinter and i have 2 classes, i am trying to call a class that i have done right under my window class. it is giving me a type error database_basket , name of the class is not callable. can someone give me a hint?

[This is the problem that i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYnbI.png)

```py
class Window3:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Payment")
        self.master.geometry("1500x800")
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.customer_basket = Database_Basket() # Calling the class below
        self.customer_basket.connection()


    def insert_data(self):
        if len(self.prod_id_var.get()) != 0:
            self.customer_basket(self.prod_id_var.get(), self.prod_name_var.get(), self.prod_qty_var.get(),self.prod_price_var.get())
            self.basket_listbox.delete(0, END)
            self.basket_listbox.insert(END, self.prod_id_var.get(), self.prod_name_var.get(), self.prod_qty_var.get(),self.prod_price_var.get())


class Database_Basket:

    def connection(self):
        print("Database is now connected")
        db_conn = sqlite3.connect("basketinfo.db")
        cursor = db_conn.cursor()
        my_query = "create table if not exists tblbasket(product_id integer primary key, prod_name text, quantity text, price text) "
        cursor.execute(my_query)
        db_conn.commit()
        db_conn.close()
        print("Database connection is finished")

    def data_entry(self, prod_id, prod_name, quantity, price):
        print("Data Entry Method is called")
        connection = sqlite3.connect("basketinfo.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        insert_query = "insert into tblbasket value(?,?,?,?)"
        cursor.execute(insert_query, (prod_id, prod_name, quantity, price))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        print("Data Entry Method is finished")
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Pictures aren't searchable, and the visually impaired can't see them at all. Also, your code doesn't look to be properly formatted.

Comment: It's not telling you that you can't call the _class_, it's telling you that you can't call the _instance_ of the class.

Comment: Sorry, This is my first time posting a question. I'll be sure to add a more sensible picture next time. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to call data_entry:

```py
self.customer_basket.data_entry(self.prod_id_var.get(), self.prod_name_var.get(), self.prod_qty_var.get(),self.prod_price_var.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line :

```
self.customer_basket(....)
```

should be :

```
self.customer_basket.data_entry(.....)
```

You are trying to call the instance, where as you should be calling the data_entry method.